# Show MySQL database table in HTML table

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have a little issue with the task in the question subject.
I have an input form which is connected to the appropriate MySQL database and works fine (all the submitted data is correctly inserting in the database), also i have one PHP page, where i want to display data from the above mention database as HTML table. In localhost created via XAMPP it work perfectly - form is submitted, data inserted into the SQL table, and simultaneously it is retrieved in the other php page as HTML table. BUT, it only works on the local machine. When i deploy all that stuff on the live hosting, the first part of this still works fine (form submitting, MySQL database info inserting), but the part with retrieving data to the HTML table does not work. Here is my code of the HTML table page. Hope can find any help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="hy">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="data.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Id</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Phone</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Select 1</th>
<th>Select 2</th>
<th>Message</th>
</tr>
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password','myDB');

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
  
$sql = "SELECT id, fldName, fldEmail, fldPhone, fldDate, fldSelect, fldSelect2, fldMessage FROM tbl_connect";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_fields > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row["id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["fldName"] . "</td><td>"
            . $row["fldEmail"]. "</td><td>" .$row['fldPhone']. "</td><td>" . $row['fldDate'] . "</td><td>" . $row['fldSelect'] . "</td><td>" . $row['fldSelect2'] . "</td><td>" . $row['fldMessage'] . "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else { 
    echo "0 results"; 
}
$conn->close();
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What error do you get?

Comment: I can't see any errors. The SQL database should be shown on that page as an HTML table, but it doesn't. It seems that connection is okay, but by some reason it is not working. Still on localhost it works fine. All the submitted data shown as HTML table on that page.

Comment: Have you checked the web servers error log? Production servers are usually configured not to show error messages on the screen directly (since it potentially can cause sensitive information to be leaked and are usually not very pretty for the end user).

Comment: I checked Cpanel errors section, but it's empty. I guess there is something wrong with connection code, but can't figure out what. because the submition and inserting into database works fine, but outputing that informaiotn not

Comment: Do you see "Connected successfully" on the page? Have you double checked that you're inserting into database myDB?

Comment: Yes, that message is displayed, also displayed "0 results". It looks like there is no access to the table rows.

Comment: I see if ($result->num_fields > 0)
should that not be  if ($result->num_rows > 0)

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.field-count.php), it seems like the procedural version is `mysqli_num_fields()` while the OOP counter part is `$result->field_count`, not `$result->num_fields`. But as @Heinz said, it should probably be `$result->num_rows` either way. Not sure why that would work on XAMPP but not in prod though? Might be different PHP versions?

Comment: Yeah, thanks! That worked, it looks like problem was with edited and not saved files. Thank you all.